# Nested loops and terminating condition in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

I have a situation here where in I have 2 loops such that,

```
1.Loop Controller (runs n times)
   2. While Controller (exits based on HTTP response below || after some time gap)
     3. HTTP Sampler
```

Now, I planned to write a Beanshell Post processor such that it parses the HTTP result and updates a ${TERMINATION_CONDITION} variable which can be used in While loop termination.

However, I want that ${TERMINATION_CONDITION} to be reset such that when the Outer most loop(i.e Loop Controller) comes in for the second time, it allows the inner While loop to be re executed.

In my case this is not happening as the ${TERMINATION_CONDITION} is not updated properly.

My question is:

1. When does post processor get executed if I add one under 
      a) HTTP Sampler as parent
      b) While Loop Controller as parent
      c) Loop Controller as parent
2. How can we reset a variable after an iteration of the inner loop?

Please help me understand. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. About execution order you should read [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder). If you wanna use Beanshell without it being PostProcessor, you could use [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler). Always have in mind that JMeter follows test plan hierarchy!
2. You can reset variables in few different ways. The simplest one is probably with beanshell by re-initializing them. Just put one Beanshell Sampler on the end of the loop and in it reset what you want.

E.g.

```
vars.put("variable1", null);
vars.put("variable2", "");
// or what ever you want...
```

Comment: Yes Ivan. Thank you! None of the blogs and posts I saw inform the importance of the Test Plan Hierarchy. I had used the same approach after going through the same link you had given. I have used vars.remove("VAR"); to reset the var which works in my case.